# How to insert points on a map in R

Tags: r, shapefile, rgdal

The code below generates a map of a state of a specific country. However, I would like to insert the points of some properties in this generated map. For this, I inserted the coordinates of the properties.

```
Points_properties = structure (list(Properties=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), Latitude = c(-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.924161,-24.95579, -24.94557, -24.93267),
Longitude = c(-49.994889, -49.990162,-50.004343, -50.007371, -50.01542, -50.00702)), row.names=c(NA,6L), class="data.frame")

> Points_properties
  Properties  Latitude Longitude
1          1 -24.93047 -49.99489
2          2 -24.95575 -49.99016
3          3 -24.92416 -50.00434
4          4 -24.95579 -50.00737
5          5 -24.94557 -50.01542
6          6 -24.93267 -50.00702
```

Executable code below:

```
library(rgdal)

temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
download.file("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip",temp)

unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
shp <- readOGR(temp2)

plot(shp)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many libraries that allow you to add points to the graph.

Becuse your values are so close to each other in your example, it looks like one point is plotted.

In base R:

```
plot(shp)

points(x = Points_properties$Longitude, y= Points_properties$Latitude, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. But what code does to insert these points in the map properly?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I'm not following